# Screenshot of X from tty

Tags: x11, tty, screenshot

Using Xvfb I can launch an application and take a screenshot.

What I'm wondering about is how to capture from an existing (dormant) X session.

Say from tty or over ssh.

From what I understand windows are unmapped and does not exist to preserve resources. Are there some tool that can map existing windows, workspaces etc in a virtual windowmanager and take a snap?

Or can one perhaps use `libx11` and create a snap by using `XShmCreateImage` or similar?

Comment: Is `xwd -root | convert - /tmp/image.jpg` what you are looking for?

Comment: @jippie: Perhaps. Problem is that as windows are unmapped there is nothing for xwd to dump - resulting in black image. (Try that command from i.e. tty1 `xwd -display :0 -root | convert xwd:- /tmp/0.png`)

Comment: unsure what you mean by 'unmapped'

Comment: @jippie: They do not reside in memory. As I understand it: When you are on your workspace - it is active - the pixels are mapped in memory for the GPU to process and render on screen. When workspace is switched or exited (I.e by Ctrl-Alt-F1) these maps are unmapped (to free up resources) - thus there is nothing in the "display buffer" - and gives a black image.

Comment: I see what you mean, thnx for the explanation. Don't know the answer in this case though.

Comment: OK. Thanks for a good try :). At least I have found some other nice things in this endeavour. As `sudo cat /dev/vcs1` or the more friendly `sudo setterm -dump 1 -file tty1.dump` - tho that is completely off the mark :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can "turn on" the X tty manually from command line, without ctrl-alt-F(x).

If X is on tty 7, and you login a text terminal

```
chvt 7 ; DISPLAY=0.0 xwd -root > screendump.xwd ; chvt 1
```

However, **xhost + localhost** must be issue within the xsession, else xwd cannot connect to x server.

This allow you to do it from ssh session.

PS: In theory, with [MTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_Technology_Device), it should be possible to do screen capture from video card memory. Thus without first "waking" the X session.

Comment: Thank you for a good post. I'm looking into it. One of my major issues is that I am an old windows'er and having some problems grasping how everything is knitted together. X server, X window manager, access and composing. But getting there.

Comment: @Sukminder Do you have difficult setting this up or need more instruction regarding this?